# Identifying heirarchical groupings from a Parent-Child associaiton list in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to identify groupings of accounts from a Parent-Child association table in SQL. Rather than a big hierarchy tree, I am dealing with many small trees and I need to identify each Tree as a unique Group in order to label related accounts.

[image: I have visualized what the hierarchy looks like here]

I have two tables, a table of all Unique ID's:

```
+------+-------+
|  ID  | Group |
+------+-------+
| A    | NULL  |
| B    | NULL  |
| C    | NULL  |
| etc. | NULL  |
+------+-------+
```

And a Table showing Parent - Child association between them:

```
+--------+-------+
| Parent | Child |
+--------+-------+
| A      | D     |
| A      | E     |
| B      | F     |
| B      | G     |
| B      | C     |
| C      | H     |
+--------+-------+
```

I Need to Fill the Group field of my first table so that I can identify all accounts which have a direct or indirect relationship eg:

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Group |
+----+-------+
| A  |     1 |
| B  |     2 |
| C  |     2 |
| D  |     1 |
| E  |     1 |
| F  |     2 |
| G  |     2 |
| H  |     2 |
+----+-------+
```

Where I'm struggling is that a Parent could be a Child to another Parent eg:

Parent B -> Parent -> C -> Child H

These form a Group but there is no direct link between B and H and I am struggling to find a reliable way to identify all associated ID's

Comment: What is the level of data you have like how many hierarchy levels?

Comment: I have approximately 150k rows in the parent-child association table, so the dataset is too large for me to predict.
I don't expect the relationships to go too deep, but there could be a chain of 20 or more parents linked together each with a different child under them.

Comment: Can you explain why you gave 1 next to A and 2 next to B &C ...etc...

Comment: I've added a [visual diagram of the ID relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Y0p.png) to the question, in this you can see A,D and E are associated in a tree that is separate from the other ID's. I have arbitrarily named this first tree Group 1, whereas the other accounts form a separate Group 2.

Answer (score 2):

This type of logic requires a recursive CTE.  The idea is to start at the parents and work your way down the hierarchy:

```
with cte as (
      select row_number() over (order by node) as grp, 
             n.node as ultimate_parent, n.node as node, 1 as lev
      from nodes n
      where not exists (select 1 from pc where pc.child = n.node)
      union all
      select cte.grp, cte.ultimate_parent, pc.child, lev + 1
      from cte join
           pc
           on cte.node = pc.parent
     )
update nodes
    set grp = cte.grp
    from cte
    where cte.node = nodes.node;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=80f9f49d45b122ad29404e7d89899b0f) is a db<>fiddle.